# How do I fit my webpage to remove scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm having issues properly setting the width of my webpage. For some reason, some of my pages have a horizontal scrollbar, whereas other fit perfectly fine. I've attached my layout template below, and I extend the rest of my html pages in the `{% block body %}{% endblock %}` placeholder.

**How can I remove the horizontal scrollbar on all pages?** I thought if I correctly set the width of the body element in my layout, then all my pages would fit accordingly.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url_for('static', filename='css/output.css')}}" />
    <link rel="icon" href="{{url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')}}" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@animxyz/core">
  </head>

  <body class="font-Vollkorn bg-black w-screen h-fit">
    <div id="modal" class="xyz-in bg-black w-screen h-full opacity-75 fixed z-20 hidden" xyz="fade"></div>
    <header class="w-screen bg-black sticky top-0 z-10">
    <div class="sm:flex sm:justify-between">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between px-2 py-2">
      <div>
        <a class="text-white font-bold text-xl" href="/"
        >Corner Hair Salon</a>
      </div>
      <div class="sm:hidden">
        <button type="button" class="block" onclick="myFunction()">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6 fill-current text-white"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M3.75 6.75h16.5M3.75 12h16.5m-16.5 5.25h16.5"/></svg>
       </button>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-white px-1 pb-1 hidden sm:flex sm:items-center sm:pb-0" id="myLinks">
        <a href="service" class="block px-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-500 ">Services</a>
        <a href="appt" class="mt-1 block px-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-500 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-2">Book an Appointment</a>
        <a href="gallery" class="mt-1 block px-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-500 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-2">Photo Gallery</a>
        <a href="login" class="mt-1 block px-1 rounded hover:bg-gray-500 sm:mt-0 sm:ml-2">Employee Sign-In</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex flex-col space-y-1">
      <div class="bg-white w-full xyz-in" style="height: 3px" xyz="left-100%""></div>
      <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 2px"></div>
      <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 1px"></div>
    </div>
  </header>

  {% block body %}{% endblock %}

      <div class="space-y-1 w-screen bottom-0">
        <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 1px"></div>
        <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 2px"></div>
        <div class="bg-white w-full" style="height: 3px"></div>
        <div class="flex relative bg-white w-full h-24 items-center justify-center">
          <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='img/logo.png')}}" class="absolute top-1/2 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 h-20 object-contain"></img>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <script src="{{url_for('static', filename='js/script.js')}}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Bad Fit (w/ Horizontal Scrollbar)**
[image: Bad fit (horizontal scrollbar)]

**Good Fit (w/o Horizontal Scrollbar)**
[image: Good fit (no horizontal scrollbar]

Comment: use the css styling "overflow-x: hidden;"

Answer (score 0):

Just from your screen shot, it looks like maybe when the web page has enough vertical content for the vertical scroll bar to appear, that takes up 5-10 pixels, but your horizontal content doesn't adjust, hence the horizontal bar.

I'm wondering if the viewport meta at the top of your page, where you set the width to "device-width" is causing the issue. Try removing or modifying that meta. I typically find that a simple "width=100%" is enough to cause my top-level containers to span the full page.